# React.js: Defining custom attributes

Tags: javascript, composition, reactjs

[React has a few custom defined attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/special-non-dom-attributes.html). How can I define my own?

### Why?

I have an `Arc` component, a few usage examples below:

```
<Arc startAngle="90" endAngle="270" stroke="hsl(38, 100%, 50%)" strokeWidth="0.5" />
<Arc startAngle="45" endAngle="90" fill="hsla(38, 100%, 50%, 0.2)" />
<Arc startAngle="0" endAngle="45" className="pie-slice" />
```

`startAngle` and `endAngle` attributes are required. All the other props are DOM properties that I just "proxy" to the root node.

```
var Arc = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <path d={this.calcPath()}
            stroke={this.props.stroke}
            strokeWidth={this.props.strokeWidth}
            fill={this.props.fill}
            className={this.props.className}
        />
    },
    calcPath() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I’m not happy with the boilerplate code for every property. I want to copy all the passed properties except `startAngle` and `endAngle`.

I came up with the following API:

```
var Arc = React.createClass({
    PROPS: {startAngle: true, endAngle: true},
    render: function() {
        return <path d={this.calcPath()} copyProps={cloneShallow(this.props, this.PROPS)}/>
    }
});

function cloneShallow(obj, exclude) {
    var result = {};
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        if (!exclude.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I’d like to define `copyProps` attribute.

---

XSLT allows to tunnel attributes:

```
<path d={...}>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
</path>
```

I want something similar for React.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting React v0.12, [`transferPropsTo` are replaced by JSX Spread Attributes](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/a6e220b7097eb3c79ab7):

```
return <path {...this.props}/>
```

Comment: Is there a nice way to exclude certain properties from a spread?

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `this.transferPropsTo`:

```
return this.transferPropsTo(<path .../>);
```

If you want to omit certain props, you can explicitly set them to `null`, e.g.

```
<path startAngle={null} />
```

but if the component you transfer the props to doesn't have such a prop anyway, it's not really necessary to do that.

See the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#transferring-props-a-shortcut) for more information.

Comment: Note: [transferPropsTo will be deprecated in 0.11](https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Projects#deprecate-transferpropsto)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Yep, but for now, that's the way to do it, until we get something new :)

Comment: It's likely that transferPropsTo will never go away entirely, but we're looking at adding some alternative solutions which are easier to reason about for most cases.