# Complex SVG animation in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, reactjs

I am using React to build an animated intro that comprises three taglines paired with animated SVG icons.

I opted for [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) to manage the SVG animations, due to the solid cross-browser support it offers. This also would allow me to perform a simple [morph](http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/MaabXe) of the `d` attribute on `<path>` elements. I am combining the aforementioned with `ReactTransitionGroup`

However, I ran into the following problems while trying to make TweenMax and React play nice:

1. While opting for component state, `componentWillReceiveProps` is somehow called twice in console. This would mean, my animation method would be called twice. What is causing this and might storing the tag index using Redux be a better option in this use case?
2. The way that I am animating currently seems very crude, e.g. repeating `this.refs` and `findDOMNode()` repeatedly. Surely there must be a better way? In which ways could the structure of my code be improved?

I am completely stumped and would love to be pointed in the right direction.

Kind regards, Jason

---

### Code

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: rgb(240, 90, 48);
  font: bold 1em sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
.reveal-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.reveal-icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
.reveal-icon svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.reveal-icon .fill {
  fill: rgb(251, 163, 10);
}
.reveal-icon .mask {
  fill: rgb(240, 90, 48);
}
.reveal-icon .stroke {
  stroke: rgb(251, 163, 10);
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
.reveal-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.switch-locale {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const ReactTransitionGroup = React.addons.TransitionGroup

const UI_TEXT = {
    EN_US: {
        REVEAL: [
            { ID: 0, TEXT: 'Tagline 1' },
            { ID: 1, TEXT: 'Tagline 2' },
            { ID: 2, TEXT: 'Tagline 3' }
        ]
    },
    NL_NL: {
        REVEAL: [
            { ID: 0, TEXT: 'Slagzin 1' },
            { ID: 1, TEXT: 'Slagzin 2' },
            { ID: 2, TEXT: 'Slagzin 3' }    
        ]
    }
}

class Reveal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            index: 0,
            locale: 'EN_US'
        }
    }
    nextTagline() {
        this.setState({index: this.state.index + 1})
        console.log('this.state.index @ ' + this.state.index)
    }
    switchLocale() {
        let locale = (this.state.locale === 'EN_US') ? 'NL_NL' : 'EN_US'
        this.setState({locale})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ReactTransitionGroup className='reveal-wrap' component='div'>
                <RevealIcon tag={this.state.index} nextTag={() => this.nextTagline()} />
                <RevealText tag={this.state.index} locale={this.state.locale} key={this.state.index} />
                <SwitchLocale switchLocale={() => this.switchLocale()} />
            </ReactTransitionGroup>
        )
    }  
}

class RevealText extends React.Component {
    fadeIn(callback, delay) {
        TweenLite.fromTo(React.findDOMNode(this), 0.5,
            {
                y: '100px',
                opacity: 0
            },
            { 
                y: 0,
                delay: delay,
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut,
                onComplete: callback,
                onCompleteScope: this
            }
        )
    }
    fadeOut(callback, delay) {
        TweenLite.fromTo(React.findDOMNode(this), 0.5,
            {
                y: 0,
                opacity: 1
            },
            { 
                y: '+=100px',
                delay: delay,
                opacity: 0,
                ease: Quad.easeIn,
                onComplete: callback,
                onCompleteScope: this
            }
        )
    }
    componentWillAppear(callback) {
        //console.log('RevealText will appear')
        this.fadeIn(callback, 1)
    }
    componentDidAppear() {  
        //console.log("RevealText did appear")
    }
    componentWillLeave(callback) {  
        this.fadeOut(callback, 0)
    }
    componentDidLeave() {
        //console.log('RevealText did leave')
    }   
    componentWillEnter(callback) {
        this.fadeIn(callback, 1)
    }
    componentDidEnter() {
        //console.log("RevealText did enter")
    }        
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='reveal-text'>
                { UI_TEXT[this.props.locale].REVEAL[this.props.tag].TEXT }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class RevealIcon extends React.Component {
    componentWillAppear(callback) {
        const HAND_1 = [React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_1),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_1_MASK),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_1_THUMB)]

        const HAND_2 = [React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_2),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_2_MASK)]

        const HAND_3 =  React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES)

        const HAND_4 = [React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_1),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_2),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_3),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_4),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_5),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_6),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_7),
                        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.HAND_LINES_8)]

        let anim = new TimelineMax({
            delay: 2,
            onComplete: this.props.nextTag,
            onCompleteScope: this
        })

        anim.fromTo(HAND_1, 0.5,
            {
                y: '-=100px',
                x: '+=100px',
                opacity: 0
            },
            {
                y: 0,
                x: 0,
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            })
            .fromTo(HAND_2, 0.5,
            {
                y: '-=100px',
                x: '-=100px',
                opacity: 0
            },
            {
                y: 0,
                x: 0,
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }, '-=0.20')
            .fromTo(HAND_3, 0.75,
            {
                scaleX: 0.5,
                scaleY: 0.5,
                transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
            },
            {   
                scaleX: 1,
                scaleY: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            })          
            .fromTo(HAND_4, 0.5,
            {
                opacity: 0,
            },
            {   
                opacity: 1,
                ease: Quad.easeOut
            }, '-=0.75')
            .fromTo(HAND_4, 1,
            {
                'stroke-dasharray': '25px',
                'stroke-dashoffset': '0px'
            },
            {
                'stroke-dasharray': '25px',
                'stroke-dashoffset': '25px',
                ease: Power3.easeOut
            }, '-=0.75')
            .set({}, {}, '+=1')

            // .set is used to lengthen the animation by 1 second
    } 
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('RevealIcon will receive props', 'nextProps.tag: ' + nextProps.tag)

        if(nextProps.tag === 1){
            // Animation code / reference to method here
        } else if (nextProps.tag === 2) {
            // Animation code / reference to method here
        } else if (nextProps.tag === 3) {
            // Animation code / reference to method here
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='reveal-icon' >
                <svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0, 0, 200, 200">
                    <path ref="HAND_1" className="fill" d="M146.8,79.9l-55.2,55.2c-1.8,1.8-4.8,1.8-6.7,0c-1.8-1.8-1.8-4.8,0-6.7h0l18.4-18.4l-3.3-3.3
                    l-18.4,18.4c-0.9,0.9-2.1,1.4-3.3,1.4s-2.5-0.5-3.3-1.4c-0.9-0.9-1.4-2.1-1.4-3.3c0-1.3,0.5-2.5,1.4-3.3L93.3,100L90,96.7
                    l-18.4,18.4c-1.8,1.8-4.8,1.8-6.7,0c-1.8-1.8-1.8-4.8,0-6.7l41.8-41.8l-3.3-3.3L61.5,105c-3.7,3.7-3.7,9.7,0,13.4
                    c1.8,1.8,4.3,2.8,6.7,2.8c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0,2.5,1,4.9,2.8,6.7c1.8,1.8,4.2,2.8,6.7,2.8c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0
                    c-0.2,2.6,0.7,5.3,2.7,7.3c1.8,1.8,4.3,2.8,6.7,2.8c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8l55.2-55.2L146.8,79.9z"/>
                    <path ref="HAND_2_MASK" className="mask" d="M138.5,105l-22.7-22.7L83.3,49.8L49.8,83.3l32.5,32.5l22.7,22.7
                    c1.8,1.8,4.3,2.8,6.7,2.8c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8c2-2,2.9-4.7,2.7-7.3c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c2.5,0,4.9-1,6.7-2.8
                    c1.8-1.8,2.8-4.2,2.8-6.7c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8c1.8-1.8,2.8-4.2,2.8-6.7
                    C141.2,109.2,140.2,106.8,138.5,105z"/>
                    <path ref="HAND_2" className="fill" d="M138.5,105L83.3,49.8l-3.3,3.3l55.2,55.2c0.9,0.9,1.4,2.1,1.4,3.3c0,1.3-0.5,2.5-1.4,3.3
                    c-1.8,1.8-4.8,1.8-6.7,0L110,96.7l-3.3,3.3l18.4,18.4c0.9,0.9,1.4,2.1,1.4,3.3c0,1.3-0.5,2.5-1.4,3.3c-0.9,0.9-2.1,1.4-3.3,1.4
                    s-2.5-0.5-3.3-1.4L100,106.7l-3.3,3.3l18.4,18.4c1.8,1.8,1.8,4.8,0,6.7c-1.8,1.8-4.8,1.8-6.7,0L53.2,79.9l-3.3,3.3l55.2,55.2
                    c1.8,1.8,4.3,2.8,6.7,2.8c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8c2-2,2.9-4.7,2.7-7.3c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c2.5,0,4.9-1,6.7-2.8
                    c1.8-1.8,2.8-4.2,2.8-6.7c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8c1.8-1.8,2.8-4.2,2.8-6.7
                    C141.2,109.2,140.2,106.8,138.5,105z"/>
                    <path ref="HAND_1_MASK" className="mask" d="M116.7,49.8l-5,5l-3.3-3.3c-1.8-1.8-4.2-2.8-6.7-2.8c-2.5,0-4.9,1-6.7,2.8
                    L73.2,73.2c-3.7,3.7-3.7,9.7,0,13.4c1.8,1.8,4.3,2.8,6.7,2.8c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8l20.1-20.1l5-5l8.4-8.4L116.7,49.8z"/>                   
                    <path ref="HAND_1_THUMB" className="fill" d="M116.7,49.8l-5,5l-3.3-3.3l0,0c-1.8-1.8-4.2-2.8-6.7-2.8c-2.5,0-4.9,1-6.7,2.8
                    L73.2,73.2c-3.7,3.7-3.7,9.7,0,13.4c1.8,1.8,4.3,2.8,6.7,2.8c2.4,0,4.8-0.9,6.7-2.8l20.1-20.1l-3.3-3.3L83.3,83.3
                    c-1.8,1.8-4.8,1.8-6.7,0s-1.8-4.8,0-6.7l21.7-21.7c0.9-0.9,2.1-1.4,3.3-1.4c1.3,0,2.5,0.5,3.3,1.4l6.7,6.7l8.4-8.4L116.7,49.8z"/>
                    <g ref="HAND_LINES">
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_8" className="stroke" x1="32.6" y1="32.6" x2="49.4" y2="49.4"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_7" className="stroke" x1="4.7" y1="100" x2="28.4" y2="100"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_6" className="stroke" x1="32.6" y1="167.4" x2="49.4" y2="150.6"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_5" className="stroke" x1="100" y1="195.3" x2="100" y2="171.6"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_4" className="stroke" x1="167.4" y1="167.4" x2="150.6" y2="150.6"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_3" className="stroke" x1="195.3" y1="100" x2="171.6" y2="100"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_2" className="stroke" x1="167.4" y1="32.6" x2="150.6" y2="49.4"/>
                        <line ref="HAND_LINES_1" className="stroke" x1="100" y1="4.7" x2="100" y2="28.4"/>  
                    </g>                                            
                </svg>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class SwitchLocale extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button className='switch-locale' onClick={this.props.switchLocale}>
                Switch locale
            </button>
        )
    }
}

React.render(<Reveal/>, document.getElementById('react-root'))

</script>
```

On the left, the animation I currently have created in React, on the right, the icons I still have to implement in the same manner.

[image: Tagline animation][image: Tagline icons]

Comment: 1) You could check whether `nextProps === this.props` and call the animation based on the result of that.
2) Not sure that there's a better way other than `findDOMNode`

Comment: @pmilla1606 Thank you! I will see how that will work out. I was hoping there was a way that would prevent me from writing endless amounts of `findDOMnode`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js: Defining custom attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852422/react-js-defining-custom-attributes)